# How to use android.graphics.drawable.bitmapdrawable in android?

Tags: android, drawable

so I have used a function to create drawable from imagepath, and I get:
android.graphics.drawable.bitmapdrawable@numbers

How do I use it? can it be used as ID?
for example with normal drawable I would write like:
findViewById(R.drawable.name);
can I use same here?

findViewById(android.graphics.drawable.bitmapdrawable@numbers);

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use findViewById(R.drawable.name), you have to use R.id.someId